# How to simplify integrals in the conditionals/marginals in a Bayesian Network

Tags: machine-learning, bayesian-network

[image: bayesian network]

I'm trying to calculate the conditionals within a Bayesian network as shown in the picture, e.g. $P(X_t|X_{t-1}, S)$, which resorts to the calculation of the marginals $P(X_{t-1}, S)$ and $P(X_t, X_{t-1}, S)$ because
$$P(X_{t-1}|X_t, S)=\frac{P(X_t, X_{t-1},S)}{P(X_{t-1},S)}$$

In the Bayesian network, the joint probability can be written as
$$P(X_{t-2}, X_{t-1}, X_t, X_{t+1}, S) = P(X_{t-2})P(X_{t-1}|X_{t-2})P(X_t|X_{t-1},)P(X_{t+1}|X_t) P(S|X_{t-2},X_{t-1},X_t)$$
Therefore the marginals can be calculated by integrating the unrelated variables:
$$P(X_t, X_{t-1},S) = \int{P(X_{t-2}, X_{t-1}, X_t, X_{t+1}, S)} dX_{t-2}dX_{t+1}
= \int{\int{P(X_{t-2})P(X_{t-1}|X_{t-2})P(X_t|X_{t-1},)P(X_{t+1}|X_t) P(S|X_{t-2},X_{t-1},X_t)} dX_{t-2}} dX_{t+1}
=\int{P(X_{t-2})P(X_{t-1}|X_{t-2})P(X_t|X_{t-1},)P(S|X_{t-2},X_{t-1},X_t)} dX_{t-2} $$

$$P(X_{t-1},S) = \int{P(X_{t-1}, X_t, S)} dX_t = \int{\int{P(X_{t-2})P(X_{t-1}|X_{t-2})P(X_t|X_{t-1},)P(S|X_{t-2},X_{t-1},X_t)} dX_{t-2}}dX_t $$
such that
$$P(X_{t-1}|X_t, S)=\frac{P(X_t, X_{t-1},S)}{P(X_{t-1},S)}=\frac{\int{P(X_{t-2})P(X_{t-1}|X_{t-2})P(X_t|X_{t-1},)P(S|X_{t-2},X_{t-1},X_t)} dX_{t-2} }{ \int{\int{P(X_{t-2})P(X_{t-1}|X_{t-2})P(X_t|X_{t-1},)P(S|X_{t-2},X_{t-1},X_t)} dX_{t-2}}dX_t}$$

My question is: such expressions are too heavy and not very useful for further analysis. Is there any way to simplify the integrals in the marginals in this non-parametric setting? Otherwise, is there any means if $P(S|X_{t-2},X_{t-1},X_t)$ can be written explicitly?

Great thanks!!!

Comment: Very interesting question, let us know if you figure out the answer thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend looking into d-separation and directed acyclic graphs (DAGs). For example, number 7 on page 2 [here](https://web.mit.edu/jmn/www/6.034/d-separation.pdf) and the examples [here](https://www.cs.ubc.ca/%7Eschmidtm/Courses/540-W19/L22.pdf). Since S has an edge coming to it from those three nodes, it is not conditionally independent of any of them given any of the others.

However, $x_{t+1}$ is d-separated from the rest and thus conditionally independent given $x_t$ from the other three nodes.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Actually, d-separation is already included in the expression of the joint distribution. Surely X_{t+1} is conditionally independent of other nodes given X_t, but X^{t+1} is already summed out in the integral so it shouldn't affect either the target marginal or the conditional...